# A Multiple Select question based on the Monotonicity and Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_ n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$. Then which of the following statements is/are true?

(A) If $(a_ n)$ is a monotonic sequence in $(0,1)$, then $(a_ n) \to  a$ for some $a$ in $(0,1)$ .

(B) If $(a_ n)$ is a Cauchy Sequence and $|a_ {2n} - (1 / 2022)| < 1/2022$ for all Natural $n$ then $(a_ n)\to a$ for some $a$ in $(0,1)$.

(C) If $(a_ n)$ is a cauchy sequence and $|a_ p -(1/1011)|< 1/2022 $ for all prime number $p$, then $(a_ n)\to a$ for some $a$ in $(0,1)$.

(D) If $(a_ n)$ is a Cauchy Sequence then it is monotonic.

I am Sharing my thoughts on the same.

Since option (A) says that $(a_ n)$ is a monotonic sequence in $(0,1)$ then $(a_ n) \to a$ for some $a$ in $(0,1)$, taking a counter as $(a_ n) = 1/n$ for $n \ge 2$ we get $a = 0$, i.e. $a$ is in $[0,1)$. So False.

Option (B) claims $(a_n)$ being a Cauchy sequence i.e. if $(a_ n)\to L$ then $(a_ {2n}) \to L$ as well, in a similar manner I can think of option (C), but this effort didn't fetched me the right conclusion. Therefore, I am confused ! Also the option (D) I can use $(a_ n) = (-1) ^n/n$, So false. Any help in resolving my struggle with option (B) and (C).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apology, will take care in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You observed correctly that $(A)$ and $(D)$ are not true in general. Now note that for $(B)$, it follows that $a_{2n}\in (0, \frac 2{2022}) \,\,\forall n\in \mathbb N$. Take $b_n=\frac 2{2022+n}$ and note that the sequence $(b_n)$ counters $(B)$.

To analyse $(C)$, observe the following lemmata:

$1)$ If $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $y_n\in (c,d),c<d$ for all $n$, then $\lim y_n\in [c,d]$.

$2)$ If $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$ and has a subsequence that converges to $x$ then $(x_n)$ also converges to $x$.

For $(C)$, $a_p\in (\frac 1{2022},\frac 3{2022})$ for all prime $p>0$. The sequence $(a_p)$ is bounded and hence by [Bolzano Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20in%20real,n%20has%20a%20convergent%20subsequence.) has a convergent subsequence $(a_{p_k})$, which converges to $a\in [\frac 1{2022},\frac 3{2022}] $ by $(1)$. Since $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, $\lim a_n=a$ by $(2)$.

Comment: +1. For (C): The set $\{ n : |a_n-a|\ge 1/2022\}$ is finite. But if $a\not\in (1/2022,1/2)$ and if $p$ is prime then  $|a_p-a|\ge 1/2022$   because $a_p\in (2/2022,3/2022)$ .